# I want to filter a new dataset based on multiple selections in a separate reactive table

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a new filtered data set based on multiple selected rows in a reactive table. I can do this if a single row is selected but don't know how to do this for multiple selections.

This is my code for the data table to select from:

```
output$tbl<-DT:: renderDataTable({
    DT:: datatable(df,
        filter='top,
        rownames= F,
        selection=list(mode='single', target='row'),
        options=list(lengthMenu=c(3,6,15), pageLength=6, scrollx=T))})
```

And this is to record relevant data selection from the table to graph

```
tbl2<-reactive({
    req(input$tbl_rows_selected)
        table_row_selected <-df[input$tbl_rows_selected,]
    sel<- as.character(table_row_selected$Category) 

    tbl_plot<-df %>%
        filter(Category == sel) %>%
        group_by(Category) %>%
        select(Category, a,b,c) 
    tbl_plot
})
```

What I want to do is change 
`selection=list(mode='single', target='row')` to `selection=list(mode='multiple', target='row')` in output$tbl.

How do I change the code in tbl2 to accommodate for multiple selections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%in%` -

```
tbl_plot <- df %>%
        filter(Category %in% sel) %>%
        # rest of the code
```